# Circular Reference Entity Framework Reference Constraint Fails when Deleting Professor Entry

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have encountered a case where circular reference is inevitable, I have three Model Classes : Professor, Module, Element :

- A Professor is responsible for zero or many modules
- A module have    zero or one Professor responsible
- A module may contain several or no Elements
- Each Element is taught by one or zero prefessor

My Model Classes:

```
public class Professor{
    public Professor(){
        this.Modules = new HashSet<Module>();
        this.Elements = new HashSet<Element>();
    }
    public int ProfessorID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DayOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class Module {
    public Module() {
        this.ModuleElements = new HashSet<Element>();
    }
    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor ResponsibleProfessor { get; set; }
    public int? ProfessorID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Element> ModuleElements { get; set; }
}

public class Element {
    public int ElementID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? ProfessorID { get; set; }
    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }
}
```

My DBContext :

```
public class GI3ASPDOTNETMVCENTITYContext : DbContext {
    public GI3ASPDOTNETMVCENTITYContext() : base("name=GI3ASPDOTNETMVCENTITYContext"){}
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GI3ASPDOTNETMVCENTITY.Models.Student> Students { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GI3ASPDOTNETMVCENTITY.Models.Professor> Professors { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GI3ASPDOTNETMVCENTITY.Models.Module> Modules { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GI3ASPDOTNETMVCENTITY.Models.Element> Elements { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Module>().HasOptional(m => m.ResponsibleProfessor).WithMany(p => p.Modules).HasForeignKey(m => m.ProfessorID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Element>().HasRequired(e => e.Module).WithMany(m => m.ModuleElements).HasForeignKey(e => e.ModuleID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Element>().HasOptional(e => e.Professor).WithMany(p => p.Elements).HasForeignKey(e => e.ProfessorID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Professor>().HasMany(p => p.Elements).WithOptional(e => e.Professor).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Professor>().HasMany(p => p.Modules).WithOptional(m => m.ResponsibleProfessor).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }       
}
```

---

I have seeded the database with sample data, thus when trying to remove a Professor entry, it stops saying :

---

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Elements_dbo.Professors_ProfessorID". The conflict occurred in database "GI3_1", table "dbo.Elements", column 'ProfessorID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE
>   statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Elements_dbo.Professors_ProfessorID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "GI3_1", table "dbo.Elements", column 'ProfessorID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.
>
> Line 113:            Professor professor = db.Professors.Find(id);
>   Line 114:            db.Professors.Remove(professor); Line 115:
>   db.SaveChanges(); Line 116:            return
>   RedirectToAction("Index"); Line 117:        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of what do you want to happen when the professor is deleted. In your case I guess it has to be unassigned from related modules and elements (rather than deleting them).

Unfortunately since you cannot turn cascade operation on, you have to do that manually:

```
Professor toBeDeleted = ...;
foreach (var module in db.Modules.Where(m => m.ProfessorID == toBeDeleted.ProfessorID))
    module.ProfessorID = null;
foreach (var element in db.Elements.Where(e => e.ProfessorID == toBeDeleted.ProfessorID))
    element.ProfessorID = null;
db.Professors.Remove(toBeDeleted);
db.SaveChanges();
```